# C++ program freezes during COM port read

Tags: c++, serial-port

I am trying to write a simple program to send single characters to a program via a COM port and read the answers I get back.  I think I have working script where I can at least send commands via the com port, but when the `ReadFile` function begins it freezes.  I have the comm timeout set for 100ms, so I don't think that it is locking the port, but I may be wrong.  I am not getting any errors, and no warnings when I compile.  I am very new to C++ (normally work with python), so please be as clear a possible with your answers.

```
// comtest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "TOP! \n";
    char buffer[1];
    HANDLE file;
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
    DWORD read, written;
    DCB port;
    char init[] = ""; // e.g., "ATZ" to completely reset a modem.

    // open the comm port.
    file = CreateFile(L"COM1",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);

    std::cout << "file made \n";
    // get the current DCB, and adjust a few bits to our liking.
    memset(&port, 0, sizeof(port));
    port.DCBlength = sizeof(port);

    // set short timeouts on the comm port.
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 100;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 100;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 100;

    int N = 10;
    while (N > 1) 
    {

        std::cout << "i'm in the loop!" << N << " loops left \n";
        char command [1];
        char * commandbuff;
        std::cin >> command;
        commandbuff = &command[1];
        WriteFile(file, commandbuff, sizeof(commandbuff),&written, NULL);
        Sleep(1000);
        std::cout << "I just slept \n";
        ReadFile(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, NULL);
        N--;
    }
    // close up and go home.
    CloseHandle(file);
    return 0;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "C++ script". There are C++ *programs".

Comment: C++ array indexes start with 0, so command[1] is an invalid location. sizeof(commandbuf) is 4 because commandbuf is a pointer. So you are asking WriteFile to send 4 characters starting from an invalid address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't appear to actually call [`SetCommTimeouts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363437(v=vs.85).aspx), so the timeouts you have defined would have no way to be applied.

Comment: That was it, I didn't realize I had accidentally removed that. I know it wasn't part of the question, but do you see anything in this code that would account for me not receiving data from the port?

Comment: I don't see the `DCB` settings being populated or applied so your bit rate, handshake or whatnot might be incorrect.  Also IIRC `cin` from a terminal normally behaves line-buffered unless you do something to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving data from a com port, don't start reading unless you have first sent a command or something that gets a response. Then, it's preferable to just read one byte at a time, but if you are sending [modbus/at commands](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rs485modbus/) like I'm doing and know you're expecting 8 bytes back, then it's ok to use readfile to read 8 bytes. Most of the C++ com port examples have SetCommState, SetCommTimeouts, SetCommMask and WaitCommEvent before you can read that single byte.

Mine had an "&" on the second parameter of ReadFile. MS Visual C++ though.
Status = ReadFile(fileusb, &ReadData, sizeof(ReadData), &NoBytesRead, NULL);